# AJAX condition if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My Question is more search base but what will happen if I change readState value means other than 4 and what if i change status value from 200 and why constant values or magical Numbers are used here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no magic numbers.

All possible states you can find out there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState

Status is HTTP status code.
HTTP Codes you can see in this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

That condition means that request has finished and status is 200 - OK

Comment: These are definitely [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), in the sense of "Unique values with unexplained meaning or multiple occurrences which could (preferably) be replaced with named constants". Here 4 can be replaced with named constant XMLHttpRequest.DONE. I don't think 200 has a named constant as mapping all those status codes is probably a bit much.

Comment: Basically in the code yes, but i think author of the question mentioned "magic" as value which doesn't described at all.